# Объясните пожалуйста, что такое эндпоинт api простыми словами

Tags: python, веб-программирование, api, postman

Мне нужно понять, что такое эндпоинт, мне нужно в коде найти и проверить эндпоинт регистрации, как я понял это нужно делать через Postman, но что такое эндпоинт?

Comment: условно, это URL по которому вы посылаете запросы для получения ответа, без переменных - base URI. например. http://localhost/registration (это ендпойнт), но в этих запросах вы будете добавлять параметры регистрации

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Что означает *Postman API endpoint*:**

---

Если простыми словами, то *Postman API endpoint* это один конец канала связи.

*API* работают с использованием «запросов» и «ответов». Когда *API* запрашивает информацию у веб-приложения или веб-сервера, он получает ответ. Место, куда *API* отправляют запросы и где находится ресурс, называется конечной точкой.

Для *API* конечная точка может включать *URL*-адрес сервера или службы. Каждая конечная точка — это место, из которого *API*-интерфейсы могут получить доступ к ресурсам, необходимым им для выполнения своих функций.

**Почему API endpoint-s важны:**

---

Компании используют *API* для передачи жизненно важной информации, процессов, транзакций и многого другого. Использование *API* будет только увеличиваться с течением времени, и обеспечение целостности каждой точки взаимодействия в *API* имеет жизненно важное значение для успеха каждого *API*.

Конечные точки указывают, где *API* могут получить доступ к ресурсам, и играют ключевую роль в обеспечении правильной работы взаимодействующего с ними программного обеспечения. Короче говоря, производительность *API* зависит от его способности эффективно взаимодействовать с конечными точками *API*.

**Как используются API endpoint-s?**

---

*Шаги выполнения:*

1. Запустить *Postman API* инструмент;
2. Добавить конечную точку *Rest API*, используя *URL*-адрес поля в инструменте *Postman*:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Выбрать метод: *GET*, чтобы выполнить метод *get*. Запросы на получение не нуждаются в теле запроса.

Во вкладке *Авторизация* выбрать *Ключ* как *APIKEY* и ввести значение в текстовое поле *Значение*, как показано на рисунке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. Нажать кнопку «*Send*», чтобы выполнить вызов *API*.

Код состояния успешного ответа на вызов *API* должен быть *200* OK/*201* создан и т.д.

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Более подробно можно почитать по следующим ссылкам:

[Ссылка №1](https://smartbear.com/learn/performance-monitoring/api-endpoints/);
[Ссылка №2](https://www.techtarget.com/searchapparchitecture/definition/API-endpoint);
[Ссылка №3](https://learning.postman.com/docs/developer/postman-api/intro-api/#:%7E:text=The%20Postman%20API%20endpoints%20let,stored%20in%20your%20Postman%20account.);
[Ссылка №4](https://www.testingdocs.com/how-to-execute-rest-api-call-using-postman/) (вспомогательные иллюстрации для ознакомления).